# recursive sums for a non_uniform list

Tags: python, list

```
def _findsum (arr, N): 
     if len(arr)== 1: 
        return arr[0] 
     else: 
        return arr[0]+_findSum(arr[1:], N) 

arr =[] 
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
N = len(arr) 
ans =_findSum(arr,N) 
print (ans)


_findsum(arr,N)
```

OutPut= 15

I need to write a recursive program to sum all elements of a non-uniform nested list.

I need the code to print something similar to the list below.

```
[7, [4, 6], 2, [1, 3, 5]].
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is the last list an input? an output? Please read [ask] and give a clear problem statement with sample inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Fullfungo. that is exactly what I mean that it should return [a, [b, c], b, [a, b, c]]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear but I'm guessing you need to print the sum of all the numbers present in the parent list. Here's a hint.

In the function, iterate through the list which is passed as a parameter. If the type of the current element is `list`, call the function with that list as the parameter. If not, return the sum of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
def findsum(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    first = arr[0]
    rest  = arr[1:]
    if type(first) == list:
        return findsum(first) + findsum(rest)
    else:
        return first + findsum(rest)

x = [1, [[2, 3], 4]]
print(findsum(x)) # returns 10
```

If I understood your question correctly, this program should return the sum of the elements in your nested list.
A shorter version looks like this:

```
def findsum(arr):
    return sum((findsum(element) if (type(element) == list) else element) for element in arr)

x = [7, [[2,[-1]]]]
print(findsum(x)) # returns 8
```